# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetchBans')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im trying to make a command with in my Discord bot to make unban a person. When I finnished the code I got an error. The error is Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetchBans'). The code I use to make it is

```
message.guild.cache.fetchBans().then(async bans => {
            if (bans.size === 0) return message.channel.send("No one is banned on the server!")
            let bannedUser = bans.find(ban => ban.user.id == userID)
            if (!bannedUser) return message.channel.send("This user isn't banned!")
            await message.guild.members.unban(bannedUser.user, reason).catch(err => {
                return message.channel.send("Something went wrong!")
            }).then(() => {
                let embed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor("GREEN")
                    .setTitle(`Member unbanned!`)
                    .setDescription("")
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter(this.client.user.username)

            embed.addField(`member = ${target.username}`, `reason = ${reason}`, false)


            message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});

            if (row[0].logs_channel != null) this.client.channels.cache.get(row[0].logs_channel).send({embeds: [embed]})

            message.delete()
        })
```

The line where it goes wrong is this line:

```
 message.guild.cache.fetchBans().then(async bans => {
```

When I run this command it will give the error. I also tried to do something else. The code i tried else for that line is:

```
message.guild.fetchBans().then(async bans => {
```

This line also gave an error that says: TypeError: message.guild.fetchBans is not a function.

I don't know what i can do about this. I hope somebody can help me.

Node.js version: 16.9.1
discord.js version: 13.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=bans) there is no `fetchBans` on `Guild`. Maybe you're looking for `message.guild.bans.fetch()`.

It's also worth noting that `message.guild` is nullable - if the message was a direct message (not sent in a guild) it will be null.